# Ubuntu 20.04 Unable to apt update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

Good Morning,

I have been an Ubuntu user for 12 years and now I am encountering a problem which prevents me from installing new software on all my Ubuntu 20.04 systems.

When I do apt update:

```
michael_uman@ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-7th ~ $ sudo apt update
Hit:5 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                          
Hit:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease                                                                                                                                   
Hit:8 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                                                             
Hit:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                      
Hit:6 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease                                                         
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                            
Ign:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Err:10 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 144.161.106.55 443]
Err:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 144.161.106.55 443]
Err:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 144.161.106.55 443]
Err:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 144.161.106.55 443]
Reading package lists... Done                     
E: The repository 'http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
michael_uman@ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-7th ~ $
```

This only started happening this morning. Yesterday I believe I was able to update the repos. This is happening both in my Native Ubuntu 20.04 and my Ubuntu 20.04 VM.

Any hints why this is happening?

Thank you,
Michael Uman

```
michael_uman@ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-7th ~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
michael_uman@ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-7th ~ $
```

Comment: Ask Microsoft why their repo uses an untrusted certificate.

Comment: I dont really care about the Microsoft cert, the problem is really with the Ubuntu certificates. I am trying to install a standard dev package libasound2-dev and am unable to.

Comment: Ok, I tried again, now it's been 3 hours since originally encountering this. Now the apt update works. It seems whatever certificate was problematic is now working. Sorry I opened this, I should have waited. I was hoping to hear an explanation but at this point this issue is resolved.

Comment: Ubuntu is not responsible for Microsoft breaking their certificates (temporary). In worst case, remove the the file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` containing the Microsoft repo.